# GlassPane wont show Background Image applied to it

Tags: java, swing

this method will get the glasspane from the JFrame, thats reference is stored in an JPanel object, I am using getGraphics from JPanel object to get graphics reference and then trying to draw a background image for the glasspane, when i run this code it shows the background image for a flicker and then the image disappears.. i tried many ways like using getClass.getResources(path) instead of File or extending the JPanel and setting image in that it had the same result.

```
private void createProfile()
    {
        gls = (JPanel) mainUi.getGlassPane();

        gls.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        Graphics g = gls.getGraphics();
        BufferedImage img=null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("/data/images/Lighthouse.jpg"));
            System.out.println("Hello");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, gls.getWidth()
                ,gls.getHeight(), null);
        //gls.removeAll();


        JPanel profileName = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel profileTitlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        profileTitlePanel.setSize(0, 20);
        profileTitlePanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        JLabel profileTitleLabel = new JLabel("  Create New Profile                      ");
        profileTitleLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        profileTitleLabel.setFont(getFont(Font.BOLD,20));
        profileTitlePanel.add(profileTitleLabel);

        profileName.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, profileTitlePanel);

        JPanel profileSelection = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
        profileSelection.add(new JPanel());
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("   Enter Your Name : ");
        Font font = getFont(Font.HANGING_BASELINE,16);
        nameLabel.setFont(font);
        profileSelection.add(nameLabel);


        final JTextField name = new JTextField();

        name.setFont(font);
        profileSelection.add(name);

        profileSelection.add(new JPanel());

        JPanel okClear = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                File file = new File("data/profiles/"+name.getText()+"/save");
                try {
                    if(!file.exists())
                    {
                        file.mkdirs();
                        new File("data/profiles/"+name.getText()+"/saves.dat").createNewFile();
                        noProfile=false;

                        System.out.println("The Current Profile -> "+noProfile);

//                      mainWindow();
                        currentProfile = name.getText();
                        new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data/state.dat")).writeBoolean(noProfile);
                        new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data/current_profile.dat")).writeUTF(currentProfile);
                        //new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)).writeInt(1);
                        gls.setVisible(false);
                        mainUi.repaint();
                        mainWindow();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        createProfile();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        okClear.add(ok);
        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                name.setText("");
            }

        });
        okClear.add(clear);

        profileSelection.add(okClear);

        profileName.add(profileSelection);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.ipadx= 10;
        gbc.ipady = 10;


        profileName.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        profileName.setSize(400, 250);

        gls.add(profileName,gbc);



        gls.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `getGraphics`, this is not how custom painting is done in Swing.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

You should create your own component, possibly using a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method to perform you custom painting there.

Don't forget to make the component transparent, using `setOpaque(false)` and apply to to the root pane using `setGlassPane(...)`

See [How to use root panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was naive here, so i didn't know values of comments earlier, So i am thanking you now.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing into a graphics object of a component when not being called from the redraw mechanism of swing does nothing.

You should create your own JPanel derived class. Implement the paintComponent(Graphics g) method on it, and do your drawing there, with the passed in graphics object.

Then take that JPanel, and call frame.setGlassPane(thatpanel);

Comment: *"Drawing into a graphics object of a component when not being called from the redraw mechanism of swing does nothing"* - Technically, that's not true, it does something, but it won't be updated the next time the component is repainted ;) - Nit pack